# Input channel destroyed, problem with firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So the app runs normally but whenever i put information to update firebase it always says channel input destroyed and when i check the firebase database it's not updated, i checked on internet some people solved the problem by chnging database rules but it didn't work for me, i have my email and password signup method enabled also... Please help

```
public void registerUser()
    {
        String email = signupActivityEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = signupActivityPassword.getText().toString();
        String fullName = signupActivityFullName.getText().toString().trim();

        mFirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(SignupActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()
        {

            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
            {

                if(task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    User user = new User(fullName, email);

                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users: ").child(Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                            .getCurrentUser()).getUid()).setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
                        {
                            if (task.isSuccessful())
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Registration Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                startActivity(new Intent(SignupActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "internal error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "external error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Logcat

```
 2020-09-26 23:03:50.448 18941-18941/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2020-09-26 23:03:50.449 18941-18941/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
2020-09-26 23:03:50.455 18941-18941/? I/ctivity.classe: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2020-09-26 23:03:52.213 18941-18941/activity.classes I/FirebaseApp: Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
2020-09-26 23:03:52.293 18941-18970/activity.classes I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:17 and remote module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:0
2020-09-26 23:03:52.293 18941-18970/activity.classes I/DynamiteModule: Selected local version of com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite
2020-09-26 23:03:52.314 18941-18970/activity.classes W/ctivity.classe: Unsupported class loader
2020-09-26 23:03:52.317 18941-18970/activity.classes W/ctivity.classe: Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
2020-09-26 23:03:52.353 18941-18976/activity.classes W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
2020-09-26 23:03:52.367 18941-18941/activity.classes I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
2020-09-26 23:03:52.404 18941-18979/activity.classes W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
2020-09-26 23:03:52.417 18941-18979/activity.classes I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
2020-09-26 23:03:52.541 18941-18941/activity.classes W/ctivity.classe: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;->getOpticalInsets()Landroid/graphics/Insets; (light greylist, linking)
2020-09-26 23:03:52.541 18941-18941/activity.classes W/ctivity.classe: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->left:I (light greylist, linking)
2020-09-26 23:03:52.541 18941-18941/activity.classes W/ctivity.classe: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->right:I (light greylist, linking)
2020-09-26 23:03:52.541 18941-18941/activity.classes W/ctivity.classe: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->top:I (light greylist, linking)
2020-09-26 23:03:52.541 18941-18941/activity.classes W/ctivity.classe: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->bottom:I (light greylist, linking)
2020-09-26 23:03:52.570 18941-18980/activity.classes I/FA: App measurement initialized, version: 31049
2020-09-26 23:03:52.570 18941-18980/activity.classes I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
2020-09-26 23:03:52.571 18941-18980/activity.classes I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app activity.classes
2020-09-26 23:03:52.571 18941-18980/activity.classes D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
2020-09-26 23:03:52.577 18941-18941/activity.classes I/MultiWindowDecorSupport: updateCaptionType >> DecorView@5b34881[], isFloating: false, isApplication: true, hasWindowDecorCaption: false, hasWindowControllerCallback: true
2020-09-26 23:03:52.578 18941-18941/activity.classes D/MultiWindowDecorSupport: setCaptionType = 0, DecorView = DecorView@5b34881[]
2020-09-26 23:03:52.631 18941-18941/activity.classes W/ctivity.classe: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->getAccessibilityDelegate()Landroid/view/View$AccessibilityDelegate; (light greylist, linking)
2020-09-26 23:03:52.652 18941-18941/activity.classes W/ctivity.classe: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2020-09-26 23:03:52.655 18941-18941/activity.classes W/ctivity.classe: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
2020-09-26 23:03:52.688 18941-18941/activity.classes W/ctivity.classe: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;-><init>()V (light greylist, reflection)
2020-09-26 23:03:52.688 18941-18941/activity.classes W/ctivity.classe: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->addFontFromAssetManager(Landroid/content/res/AssetManager;Ljava/lang/String;IZIII[Landroid/graphics/fonts/FontVariationAxis;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2020-09-26 23:03:52.688 18941-18941/activity.classes W/ctivity.classe: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->addFontFromBuffer(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;I[Landroid/graphics/fonts/FontVariationAxis;II)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2020-09-26 23:03:52.688 18941-18941/activity.classes W/ctivity.classe: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->freeze()Z (light greylist, reflection)
2020-09-26 23:03:52.688 18941-18941/activity.classes W/ctivity.classe: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->abortCreation()V (light greylist, reflection)
2020-09-26 23:03:52.689 18941-18941/activity.classes W/ctivity.classe: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/Typeface;->createFromFamiliesWithDefault([Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;Ljava/lang/String;II)Landroid/graphics/Typeface; (light greylist, reflection)
2020-09-26 23:03:52.903 18941-18941/activity.classes D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
2020-09-26 23:03:52.908 18941-18941/activity.classes D/EmergencyMode: [EmergencyManager] android createPackageContext successful
2020-09-26 23:03:52.928 18941-18941/activity.classes D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=67
2020-09-26 23:03:52.930 18941-18941/activity.classes D/ViewRootImpl@4263e22[SignupActivity]: setView = DecorView@5b34881[SignupActivity] TM=true MM=false
2020-09-26 23:03:52.950 18941-18980/activity.classes I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
2020-09-26 23:03:53.057 18941-18941/activity.classes D/ViewRootImpl@4263e22[SignupActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][720,1280] new=[0,0][720,1280] result=0x7 surface={true 3592433664} changed=true
2020-09-26 23:03:53.066 18941-18985/activity.classes I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2020-09-26 23:03:53.066 18941-18985/activity.classes I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
2020-09-26 23:03:53.066 18941-18985/activity.classes I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2020-09-26 23:03:53.067 18941-18985/activity.classes D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
2020-09-26 23:03:53.080 18941-18985/activity.classes D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [720x1280]-format:1
2020-09-26 23:03:53.080 18941-18985/activity.classes D/OpenGLRenderer: eglCreateWindowSurface = 0xe82ca9e0, 0xd6203008
2020-09-26 23:03:53.122 18941-18985/activity.classes D/vndksupport: Loading /vendor/lib/hw/android.hardware.graphics.mapper@2.0-impl.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
2020-09-26 23:03:53.158 18941-18941/activity.classes D/ViewRootImpl@4263e22[SignupActivity]: MSG_RESIZED: frame=[0,0][720,1280] ci=[0,48][0,0] vi=[0,48][0,0] or=1
2020-09-26 23:03:53.159 18941-18941/activity.classes D/ViewRootImpl@4263e22[SignupActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1 1
2020-09-26 23:03:53.160 18941-18941/activity.classes D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@5b34881[SignupActivity]
2020-09-26 23:03:53.160 18941-18941/activity.classes D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -855310
2020-09-26 23:03:53.179 18941-18941/activity.classes D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@5b34881[SignupActivity]
2020-09-26 23:03:53.179 18941-18941/activity.classes D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -855310
2020-09-26 23:03:53.179 18941-18941/activity.classes D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0
2020-09-26 23:03:53.180 18941-18941/activity.classes I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
2020-09-26 23:03:53.187 18941-18953/activity.classes D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=77
2020-09-26 23:03:53.199 18941-18980/activity.classes D/FA: Connected to remote service
2020-09-26 23:03:53.199 18941-18941/activity.classes D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@5b34881[SignupActivity]
2020-09-26 23:03:53.200 18941-18941/activity.classes D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -855310
2020-09-26 23:03:53.200 18941-18941/activity.classes D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0
2020-09-26 23:04:16.506 18941-18941/activity.classes D/ViewRootImpl@4263e22[SignupActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
2020-09-26 23:04:16.582 18941-18941/activity.classes D/ViewRootImpl@4263e22[SignupActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
2020-09-26 23:04:16.610 18941-18941/activity.classes D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@5b34881[SignupActivity]
2020-09-26 23:04:16.610 18941-18941/activity.classes D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -855310
2020-09-26 23:04:16.611 18941-18941/activity.classes D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0
2020-09-26 23:04:16.619 18941-18941/activity.classes I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
2020-09-26 23:04:16.622 18941-18941/activity.classes D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=81
2020-09-26 23:04:16.622 18941-18941/activity.classes D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=77
2020-09-26 23:04:16.623 18941-18941/activity.classes D/InputMethodManager: SSI - flag : 0 Pid : 18941 view : activity.classes
2020-09-26 23:04:16.623 18941-18941/activity.classes D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@5b34881[SignupActivity]
2020-09-26 23:04:16.623 18941-18941/activity.classes D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -855310
2020-09-26 23:04:16.629 18941-18941/activity.classes D/Editor: waiting for the right moment
2020-09-26 23:04:16.653 18941-18941/activity.classes I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 3180 bytes, containing 1 windows, 9 views
2020-09-26 23:04:16.791 18941-18941/activity.classes D/ViewRootImpl@4263e22[SignupActivity]: MSG_RESIZED: frame=[0,0][720,1280] ci=[0,48][0,0] vi=[0,48][0,618] or=1
2020-09-26 23:04:19.964 18941-18941/activity.classes D/ViewRootImpl@4263e22[SignupActivity]: ViewPostIme key 0
2020-09-26 23:04:19.967 18941-18941/activity.classes D/ViewRootImpl@4263e22[SignupActivity]: ViewPostIme key 1
2020-09-26 23:04:19.996 18941-18941/activity.classes D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@5b34881[SignupActivity]
2020-09-26 23:04:19.996 18941-18941/activity.classes D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -855310
2020-09-26 23:04:19.997 18941-18941/activity.classes D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0
2020-09-26 23:04:20.005 18941-18941/activity.classes I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
2020-09-26 23:04:20.009 18941-18941/activity.classes D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=77
2020-09-26 23:04:20.009 18941-18941/activity.classes D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=81
2020-09-26 23:04:21.536 18941-18941/activity.classes D/ViewRootImpl@4263e22[SignupActivity]: ViewPostIme key 1
2020-09-26 23:04:22.598 18941-18941/activity.classes D/ViewRootImpl@4263e22[SignupActivity]: ViewPostIme key 0
2020-09-26 23:04:22.617 18941-18941/activity.classes D/ViewRootImpl@4263e22[SignupActivity]: ViewPostIme key 1
2020-09-26 23:04:23.404 18941-18941/activity.classes D/ViewRootImpl@4263e22[SignupActivity]: ViewPostIme key 1
2020-09-26 23:04:26.079 18941-18941/activity.classes D/ViewRootImpl@4263e22[SignupActivity]: ViewPostIme key 1
2020-09-26 23:04:28.411 18941-18941/activity.classes D/ViewRootImpl@4263e22[SignupActivity]: ViewPostIme key 1
2020-09-26 23:04:33.663 18941-18941/activity.classes D/ViewRootImpl@4263e22[SignupActivity]: ViewPostIme key 0
2020-09-26 23:04:33.664 18941-18941/activity.classes D/ViewRootImpl@4263e22[SignupActivity]: ViewPostIme key 1
2020-09-26 23:04:33.690 18941-18941/activity.classes D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@5b34881[SignupActivity]
2020-09-26 23:04:33.691 18941-18941/activity.classes D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -855310
2020-09-26 23:04:33.691 18941-18941/activity.classes D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0
2020-09-26 23:04:33.700 18941-18941/activity.classes I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
2020-09-26 23:04:33.704 18941-18941/activity.classes D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=81
2020-09-26 23:04:33.704 18941-18941/activity.classes D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=77
2020-09-26 23:04:35.932 18941-18941/activity.classes D/ViewRootImpl@4263e22[SignupActivity]: ViewPostIme key 0
2020-09-26 23:04:35.933 18941-18941/activity.classes D/ViewRootImpl@4263e22[SignupActivity]: ViewPostIme key 1
2020-09-26 23:04:35.959 18941-18941/activity.classes D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@5b34881[SignupActivity]
2020-09-26 23:04:35.959 18941-18941/activity.classes D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -855310
2020-09-26 23:04:35.959 18941-18941/activity.classes D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0
2020-09-26 23:04:35.967 18941-18941/activity.classes I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
2020-09-26 23:04:35.970 18941-18941/activity.classes D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=77
2020-09-26 23:04:35.970 18941-18941/activity.classes D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=81
2020-09-26 23:04:35.993 18941-18941/activity.classes I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 3428 bytes, containing 1 windows, 9 views
2020-09-26 23:04:39.588 18941-18941/activity.classes D/ViewRootImpl@4263e22[SignupActivity]: ViewPostIme key 0
2020-09-26 23:04:39.589 18941-18941/activity.classes D/ViewRootImpl@4263e22[SignupActivity]: ViewPostIme key 1
2020-09-26 23:04:39.592 18941-18941/activity.classes D/InputMethodManager: HSIFW - flag : 0 Pid : 18941
2020-09-26 23:04:39.637 18941-18941/activity.classes D/ViewRootImpl@4263e22[SignupActivity]: MSG_RESIZED: frame=[0,0][720,1280] ci=[0,48][0,0] vi=[0,48][0,0] or=1
2020-09-26 23:04:40.255 18941-18941/activity.classes D/ViewRootImpl@4263e22[SignupActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
2020-09-26 23:04:40.339 18941-18941/activity.classes D/ViewRootImpl@4263e22[SignupActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
2020-09-26 23:04:40.351 18941-18941/activity.classes I/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzao@45ea4bb
2020-09-26 23:04:40.893 18941-18941/activity.classes D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=81
2020-09-26 23:04:40.895 18941-18941/activity.classes D/ViewRootImpl@8244c23[Toast]: setView = android.widget.LinearLayout{cb94520 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0} TM=true MM=false
2020-09-26 23:04:40.920 18941-18941/activity.classes D/ViewRootImpl@8244c23[Toast]: Relayout returned: old=[0,48][720,1280] new=[228,1064][492,1152] result=0x7 surface={true 3592435712} changed=true
2020-09-26 23:04:40.923 18941-18985/activity.classes D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [264x88]-format:1
2020-09-26 23:04:40.923 18941-18985/activity.classes D/OpenGLRenderer: eglCreateWindowSurface = 0xd5e64de0, 0xd6203808
2020-09-26 23:04:40.927 18941-18941/activity.classes D/ViewRootImpl@8244c23[Toast]: MSG_RESIZED: frame=[228,1064][492,1152] ci=[0,0][0,0] vi=[0,0][0,0] or=1
```

Comment: Can you [enabling debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)) and include the output that generates?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'm sorry do u mean to change the debug level to debug ?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen anyway i edited the post with debug level logging if u mean that

Comment: I don't see any calls to the database in that output. At this point, I have no idea what the problem is. If you step through the code that you shared in a debugger, which line doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I edited the post with the whole class to avoid confusion, so this is a signup activity where i have 4 fields to enter credentials. That's the full name, email, password and confirm password, so when i click on register after entering info it should validate and then call createUserWithEmailAndPassword method and that's where the problem is

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen so in my code if task.isSuccessful() is false it will show a toast with external error on it and that's what happens when i actually click the button, so the problem here is the task for creating email and pass is never successful

Comment: There are two calls to `task.isSuccessful()` in the code you shared. Which one is failing? And what's the error message you then get when you check `task.getException()`? Note that is is much more likely that someone can help if you minimize the code needed in your question, and include the information of what is goign wrong in there too. Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I actually had only one method in the post but i tried to provide u with more information when u asked, the task which is failing is createUserWithEmailAndPassword it fails the task and says external error as i coded it to show whenever it fails

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I edited the post again to minimize the code as it was before

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a `Task` fails, log its exception to find out the cause of the failure. For example:

```
if (task.isSuccessful())
{
    Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Registration Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    startActivity(new Intent(SignupActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
}
else
{
    Log.e("Task failed", "Task failed", e);
    Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "internal error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Then find the cause of the problem in your logcat output, and address it.

Comment: Okay i have tried to add task.getException and added a System.out.println("///////////////"); line before the exception statement to know where exactly is the output of it and it didn't show any lines in between the "///////////" means there was no output from the statement

Comment: and ofcourse i put it in the fail statement (which in my case else statement)

Comment: I don't know my project is just stopped for 4 whole days because of this error and i can't find any solution on the internet...